# Send Message to a remote pc without depending on WinRM service

Tags: powershell, winrm

I am wondering if it is possible to send a system tray message or a pop-up message box to a remote pc without depending on the WinRM service. Every time i try i get an error because the service is not active in the place where i am testing and cannot be activated with normal user level access.

For the system tray msg i use this code ( works on the local pc where i am on )

```
[void]   
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = "c:\temp\shake.ico"
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Message Text" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Do you agree?"
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000)
```

For the pop-up msg i use this code

```
[void
System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(‘Microsoft.VisualBasic’)
$result = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox(“Do you agree?”,     
‘YesNoCancel,Question’, “Respond please”)
switch ($result) 
{ ‘Yes’ { “Ah good” } ‘No’ { “Sorry to hear that” } ‘Cancel’ { “Bye…” } }
```

Note that these are sample codes obtained from various powershell scripting sites and not my own ( in case someone recognises the code ).

Answer (score 2):

You need WinRM to use PowerShell remoting.

If you have file access and WMI access, then you could copy the file(s) to the remote computer and use `psexec` or WMI directly to invoke `powershell -File c:\temp\myscript.ps1` as an interactive process for the current user on the remote computer.

On a side not: If you don't have access to configure the WinRM service then you're probably not allowed to send messages to remote computers either, as this is an administrators job (in which case you would have the rights to configure WinRM).